# Pycharm - shortcut for showing results/log.html in default browser

Tags: pycharm

How can I use a shortcut (say Alt+r) to open the results/log.html in the default browser?

Why? The action is used so often.

I tried also to do this via macro's but did not succeed.

Pycharm is relatively new for me.

Comment: Why not just add a bookmark in your browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Note: I am assuming you run PyCharm on Windows)

First of all, you must define a new menu item because PyCharm shortcut keys can only execute menu items.

Go to **File > Settings > Tools > External tools** and add a new tool:

- Program: `cmd`
- Arguments: `/c start results\log.html`
- Working directory: `$ContentRoot$`

Next step is to go to **Settings > Keymap**, expand "Main Menu > Tools > External Tools", find the new tool you created above, and assign a shortcut key (beware of conflicts!)

...

Alternatively you can simply right-click on the file and choose "Open in browser".

Comment: Thank you! NICE solution. This helps for a quick start of reviewing the test results. NOTICE: after adding the external tool I had to restart Pycharm to be able to add the keymap!

Comment: Eh? I don't need to do that ... but maybe your PyCharm was busy doing things in the background and ignored new changes. But anyways, I'm glad this solves your need :-)